# How to solve Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.signOut()' on a null object reference?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have two activities (`mainactivity` and `main2activity`). I got the Google login code from GitHub Firebase login demo. When in SignIn with Google, it redirects to second activity which is the navigation drawer activity, in the drawer, I placed SignOut where it gives me error:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.signOut()' on a null object reference
```

SignOut method in `mainactivity` is

```
public void signOut() {
    // Firebase sign out
    mAuth.signOut();
    LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
    // Google sign out
    Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
            new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
                    updateUI(null);
                }
            });
}
```

This is how I called the method:

```
MainActivity ma = new MainActivity();
ma.signOut();
```

How to SignOut from drawer?

Comment: Never, ever, ever make a `new Activity();` ... Anyways, to fix the error. You need to initialize `mAuth`

Answer (score 0):

Never use new to create an Activity.  Activities should only be created by the framework.  You should have an instance of the signin from when you loggedin, use that.

Comment: i didnt get it why should i not create activity? is that bad?

Comment: Because they won't be initialized correctly.  The framework needs to initialize them, or they won't actually be valid.  And the way it does that is through startActivity.

Comment: Back when you signed in, store the resulting authentication token.  Call signout on that.

Answer (score 0):

**It's Late but some guys will found it helpful .
In Your MainAcivity.**

*Add this line of code.*

```
FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
```